# Is it a good idea to use password safes such as KeePass?

Tags: password-management, keepass

I'm starting to use KeePass as a password manager but I was wondering if such password safes are a good way to store passwords.

Could a malware dump my RAM when the safe is open and retrieve all the passwords? (Win. 7.)

I'm worried because I store the usernames and websites URLs along with the passwords so it makes it very easy to overtake all my internet accounts in just one hack.

Should I keep using this software this way?

Comment: Yes, there are tools that can extract the passwords from KeePass when in memory.